# SimpleInjector IContainerConfigurator implementation for Enterprise Library 5

Tags: enterprise-library, simple-injector

Is anyone aware of or written a SimpleInjector flavour of IContainerConfiguration for the Enterprise Library 5.  I've found one for Castle and Autofac and started to write my own but I admit I'm struggling.

For reference: [The Castle](https://github.com/moodmosaic/BonusBits.CodeSamples/blob/master/BonusBits.CodeSamples.EnterpriseLibrary/WindsorContainerConfigurator/dotNet40/WindsorContainerConfigurator/WindsorContainerConfigurator.cs) and [autofac](https://github.com/jbatte47/Autofac/blob/master/Extras/Source/Autofac.Extras.EnterpriseLibraryConfigurator/AutofacContainerConfigurator.cs) flavour